# How can I forcel Firefox to open links in emails in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook

[This link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-your-default-browser-windows-10) doesn't help, as Firefox's already my default browser:

[image]

Comment: What actually is the content of the link?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do that

**1st :** 
         Reset Settings and assign default programs again

```
Press Windows key + I to open the Settings app.
Open Apps.
Select Default apps from the left pane.
Scroll down and click on the “Reset” button.
Assign all main programs and choose Firefox from the list of available browsers.
```

**2nd:**
           Set Program associations individually

```
    Open the Settings app.
    Open Apps.
    Select Default apps from the left pane.
    Click on the “Choose default apps by file type“.
    Replace all Edge/Internet Explorer/Chrome associated files with Firefox and confirm changes.
```

**3rd :** Reinstall Firefox

if the installation get’s corrupt or incomplete, it might skip on listing Firefox as a relevant browser. That’s why you should reinstall it and, after you set it up, check the “Default apps” section again.

Ref : [Link](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-wont-allow-firefox-default-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to choose the `Set defaults by app`.

[image]

A list of all apps will appear. Select Firefox, then Manage.

[image]

Associate the type(s) or protocols(s) you want with Firefox

[image]